# Power query editor, increment column group value based on change in value in another column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a table that has 3 columns [Index], [Type], & [Count Sales]. I need to add 3 columns [Increment Group], [Cumulative Count Sales] and [Max for Group] using power query editor in PowerBI. I've tried to add a custom column but without any luck. If it can't be done with power query editor, then DAX could be a back up way, but I couldn't get that working either.

The screenshot below shows how I would implement [Increment Group] in Excel. Notice that "Bikes" on rows 11:13 is group 5 and not equal to group 1 like "Bikes" is equal to 1 on rows 2:4. I want it like this, which makes this slightly different to other questions and answers I've seen on stackoverflow. [Cumulative Count Sales] just does a cumulative count of sales by group. And [Max for Group] is the largest value from [Cumulative Count Sales] for each [Increment Group].

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: hi, i suppose the table may missed one group column as currently we can not distinguish rows2-4 form rows11-13 as two groups. If can add one column as group i think it can be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following PowerQuery script as one way to achieve what you're after

```
let
    //ignore the first 2 steps, essentially start with your table then add from the Grouped Rows step
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Index", Int64.Type}, {"Type", type text}, {"Count Sales", Int64.Type}}),
    //
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Type"}, {{"Min Index", each List.Min([Index]), type nullable number}, {"Max for Group", each List.Sum([Count Sales]), type nullable number}, {"data", each _, type table [Index=nullable number, Type=nullable text, Count Sales=nullable number]}}, GroupKind.Local),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Increment Group", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Index", "data", {"Index", "Count Sales"}, {"Index", "Count Sales"}),
    ListOffset = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded data", "ListOffset", each [Min Index] - 1, type number),
    ListItems = Table.AddColumn(ListOffset, "ListItems", each [Index] - [Min Index] + 1, type number),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(ListItems,{{"Increment Group", Order.Ascending}, {"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    ListSales = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "ListSales", each List.Range(#"Sorted Rows"[Count Sales],[ListOffset], [ListItems])),
    #"Cumulative Sales" = Table.AddColumn(ListSales, "Cumulative Sales", each List.Sum([ListSales]), type number),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Cumulative Sales",{"Index", "Type", "Count Sales", "Increment Group", "Cumulative Sales", "Max for Group"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

The *#"Grouped Rows"* step starts as a 'normal' Group By (I've used the sum of sales for the Max as this is what it appears to be in your data), which will give you the output shown below [image]

But if you go to the formula bar and add in ***, GroupKind.Local*** between the last brace and last bracket, it starts a new group every time the Type column changes. Have a look at https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/01/03/aggregating-by-local-groups-in-power-query/ or https://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/01/21/table-group-exploring-the-5th-element-in-power-bi-and-power-query/ for some more info on local grouping.

[image]

The *#"Added Index"* and *#"Expanded data"* steps are self explanatory, the *ListOffset*, *ListItems* and *#"Sorted Rows"* steps create values/ordering that are used in a List.Range formula in the *ListSales* step to create a running list of sales amts.

[image]

The *#"Cumulative Sales"* just sums the ListSales values and *#"Removed Other Columns"* tidies it up

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ben, very good instructions. The GroupKind.Local and your additional aggregation of "Data" with operator "All rows" was my knowledge gap that was very useful!